# How to handle Javascript dropdown menu in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, javascript, code

I'm trying to select a drop&down menu, select an option but I can't do it and I don't know how

The code is:

```
<div class="jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup jqx-menu-popup-officeWFM2" style="border: medium none; background-color: transparent; z-index: 17000; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: 39.3333px; left: 1086.5px; display: none; visibility: visible; width: 159px; height: 124px;">
<div style="background-color: transparent; border: none; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<ul id="jqxWidget60bb7a98" class="jqx-widget-content jqx-widget-content-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-dropdown jqx-menu-dropdown-officeWFM2 jqx-popup jqx-popup-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-l jqx-rc-l-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-b jqx-rc-b-officeWFM2" role="menu" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; display: block; top: -119px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;">
<li id="0" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Perfiles</span>
</li>
<li id="1" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Usuarios</span>
</li>
<li id="2" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Parámetros</span>
</li>
<li id="3" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item jqx-menu-item-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" role="menuitem">
<span style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: -2px;">Datos entidades</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to select the option, for example, `"Usuarios"':

This is the code for the menu, but it comes from a click button with this code

```
<div id="wfm-header-config" class="header-cell jqx-widget jqx-widget-officeWFM2 jqx-menu jqx-menu-officeWFM2 jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-widget-header jqx-widget-header-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-horizontal jqx-menu-horizontal-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2 dis_jqxMenu" role="menubar" style="outline: medium none; height: auto; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; border: medium none;" tabindex="0">
<ul class="jqx-menu-ul">
<li id="-1" class="jqx-rtl jqx-rtl-officeWFM2 jqx-item jqx-item-officeWFM2 jqx-menu-item-top jqx-menu-item-top-officeWFM2 jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-officeWFM2" style="float: right; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; padding: 2px;" role="menuitem">
<img src="resources/images/ic_settings_24.png" title="Configuración ">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

To understand the code I paste two screenshot from the upper codes

The Screenshot from the button

[image: Button menu]

The Screenshot from next window (popup) for the option selected

[image: Second window]

Sorry for the possible mistakes but I'm newer on this platform.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to open up the dropdown menu, then select the desired menu item.

The markup is not the easiest to work with because of absence of data-oriented `id`, `name` or `class` attributes. But, we can approach the problem locating elements by text and `title`:

```
// open the menu
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='wfm-header-config']/ul/li[starts-with(span/@title, 'Configuración')]")).click();

// select Usuarios from the menu
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'menu-popup')]//li[span = 'Usuarios']")).click();
```

Comment: What if the item to be clicked needs a scroll to make it visible?

Comment: Worked like a charm. For some reason, I couldn't find a single documentation to something as simple as this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution in C#.  Note that both Java and Javascript should have this same ability using query filters (for Language Integrated Queries)

```
wd.FindElements(By.Tagname("li").Where(i=>i.text=='Configuración').First().Click;
```

Comment: With selenium it is possible to find elements that are not clickable or are not fully loaded yet, therefore its best practice to find the element and then in a try/catch block check it to ensure its clickable and then click it if is.